# Gradle java project in SSH Remote Target Configuration using IntelliJ IDEA - Connect timed out

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have an java project in Intellij IDEA on Windows, that is build with gradle (wrapper). This runs fine locally. I now have specified to build/ test/ run on a SSH remote target in the "Run Targets" configuration (ssh + rsync):
[Run Target Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo6K9.png)

I can see sources being uploaded with rsync commands like this:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\rsync.exe -zar -v -e "C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -p 22 -i C:\Users\brian\Downloads\linux-aws.pem" --exclude=/build\classes\java\main --exclude=/build\classes\java\main --exclude=/build --exclude=[many excludes here] cavis-dnn-common-tests/ ec2-user@172.31.30.248:/home/ec2-user/dl4j/0viyoPzZWn/cavis-dnn/cavis-dnn-common-tests --delete
sending incremental file list

sent 532 bytes  received 17 bytes  366.00 bytes/sec
total size is 11,185  speedup is 20.37
```

Then I get a Connect timed out. With

```
#com.intellij.ssh
#org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle
```

configured for Custom Debug Log Configuration within IDEA, the log shows this:

```
2023-08-01 11:48:51,008 [330349670]   FINE - #c.i.s.SshConnectionService - Executing SSH command: cd /home/ec2-user/dl4j/0viyoPzZWn; exec env "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "serverBindingHost"="172.31.30.248" "serverBindingPort"="0" /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.19.0.7-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath '/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/util-8.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-api-8.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-api-impldep-8.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-wrapper-8.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/external-system-rt.jar' org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.proxy.Main --debug within SshjSshConnection(ec2-user@172.31.30.248)@ee18ec

2023-08-01 11:49:01,421 [330360083]   FINE - #o.j.p.g.s.t.GradleTaskManager - Gradle build launcher error
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not connect to server /172.31.30.248:35783. Tried addresses: [/172.31.30.248].
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.start$lambda$1(GradleServerRunner.kt:179)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.TargetBuildExecuter.runAndGetResult(TargetBuildExecuter.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.TargetBuildLauncher.run(TargetBuildLauncher.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.executeTasks(GradleTaskManager.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.lambda$executeTasks$1(GradleTaskManager.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:144)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.maybeFixSystemProperties(GradleExecutionHelper.java:170)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$1(GradleExecutionHelper.java:144)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$Companion.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt:187)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:140)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.executeTasks(GradleTaskManager.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.executeTasks(GradleTaskManager.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.lambda$executeTasks$0(RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.executeTasks(RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemTaskManagerWrapper.executeTasks(ExternalSystemTaskManagerWrapper.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemExecuteTaskTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemExecuteTaskTask.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.ExternalSystemRunnableState.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemRunnableState.java:323)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.ConnectException: Could not connect to server /172.31.30.248:35783. Tried addresses: [/172.31.30.248].
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.doRun(GradleServerRunner.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.start$lambda$1(GradleServerRunner.kt:176)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishTimedConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1145)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.blockingConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1183)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.tryConnect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:54)
    ... 12 more
```

The remote host I am connecting to, only has SSH port 22 open, so my local Intellij IDEA will fail to connect to the remote gradle process as indicated in the log
`org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not connect to server /172.31.30.248:35783. Tried addresses: [/172.31.30.248].`

The port is random and changes on every run, so I do not see a way to open it in the firewall of the remote host.

On the remote host side, the command

```
cd /home/ec2-user/dl4j/0viyoPzZWn; exec env "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "serverBindingHost"="172.31.30.248" "serverBindingPort"="0" /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.19.0.7-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath '/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/util-8.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-api-8.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-api-impldep-8.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-wrapper-8.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar:/home/ec2-user/dl4j-bin/external-system-rt.jar' org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.proxy.Main --debug
```

results into:

```
Gradle target server hostAddress: 172.31.30.248 port: 33829                                                                                Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incoming connection timeout                                                                         bin/exteat org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.proxy.Main.waitFor(Main.kt:211)e                                                                                        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.proxy.Main.waitForIncomingConnection(Main.kt:187)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.proxy.Main.doMain(Main.kt:48)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.proxy.Main.main(Main.kt:34)
```

**What I have tried:**
I have set up a SOCKS5 proxy using SSH, that works for the rsync and ssh connection, but still not for the above. In gradle.settings I have tried to set
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-DsocksProxyHost=sshtunnel -DsocksProxyPort=8888`